# How to sticky table header and first column of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to achieve the header column to be stuck to the top and I want the first column(after the header) to be stuck as well so what should happen is this

:[image]

This is what I have so far, I can't seem to get the rest to work. I've tried numerous methods. I am designing it for a mobile view to align the static top header with the content in the table, I am relatively new to CSS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0dnwz5a/)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head2</th>
            <th>head3</th>
            <th>head4</th>
            <th>head6</th>
            <th>head7</th>
            <th>head8</th>
            <th>head9</th>
            <th>head10</th>
            <th>head11</th>
            <th>head12</th>
            <th>head13</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
table tbody, table thead {
  display: block;
}
table thead {
  width: 600px;
}
table tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

EDIT: Corrected to row from column. Brain fart!

EDIT 2: Picture for clarification 
[image]

Comment: so, the first row, should be static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I updated it a little:

It's not perfect, but it is what you wanted.

What have I done?

I made 2 `tbody`s and placed them in separate tables, then moved the tables in the right position bellow the main `header`, and that's it.

Hope I could help.

Snippet:

```css
table tbody, table thead {
  display: block;
}
table thead {
  width: 600px;
}
table tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
}

#tb1 {
  width:50px;
  height:130px;
  margin-Left: 10px;
}
#tb2 {
  right:100px;
  width:570px;
  height:105px;
}

.one {
    float: left;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head2</th>
            <th>head3</th>
            <th>head4</th>
            <th>head6</th>
            <th>head7</th>
            <th>head8</th>
            <th>head9</th>
            <th>head10</th>
            <th>head11</th>
            <th>head12</th>
            <th>head13</th>
          </thead>
          </table>
          <table>
          
      
          <div class="one"> 
          <tbody id="tb1">
            <tr>
                <td>cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cell</td>          
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cell</td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cell</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </div>
         </table>
         
         <table style="float:left; margin-Top:-135px; margin-Left:50px;">       
          <div class="two">
           <tbody id="tb2">
            <tr>
                <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </div>
          </table>
         
         
         
         
         
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am so sorry, I meant the first row! I will edit that right now

Comment: That's what I have done, the first row is now static...you should play a little with the css in order to make it look better and accept the answer if you are astisfied. :)

Comment: .. I had it right originally, wow I am so sorry. I added a picture to the post above to make clear exactly what I meant, I saw row and must have confused myself. I need column 1 to be static along with the header and it should work on a mobile view

Comment: I just need the first column, I have the header working :)

Comment: K, give me a moment

Comment: Done, try it out.

Comment: this answer works, but the left side cell 1 needs to align with the data to the right, it was my original problem of using 2 tables

Comment: just add  `margin-Left:10px;` to the `#tb1` class in the css (updated the answer, check it out)